# Nav2 - How to create a custom behavior tree (BT) plugin/node in a separate ros2 package?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros2, ros-humble, nav2

I'm trying to create a **my own custom bt plugin**.
In the official tutorial https://navigation.ros.org/plugin_tutorials/docs/writing_new_bt_plugin.html,
I can't see an instruction or an example on how to create a behavior tree plugin in a separate ros2 package just like in this nav2 repo tutorial https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2_tutorials/tree/master where the custom plugins (custom costmap, behavior, controller and planner) are created in a separate package.

So I'm wondering, is it possible to create the bt plugin/node in a separate package? or I need to install nav2 from source and try to create the bt plugin on the */navigation2/nav2_behavior_tree/plugins* folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There's nothing special about the `nav2_behavior_tree` package. Here's one such recent example: https://github.com/open-navigation/opennav_coverage/tree/main/opennav_coverage_bt